# How to pull in dynamic content in hook_filter_FILTER_process?

Tags: 7, input-formats

I'm creating a custom input filter to replace a placeholder html comment with a simple form. However, calling drupal_get_form within a hook_filter_FILTER_process function causes the php memory limit to be exceeded.

Elsewhere I tried to do a node_load within one of these functions and the same thing happened.  I was able to work around that but this indicates it's nothing to do with the form (which is displayed elsewhere on the site anyway, and only contains a couple of fields).

The memory limit is hit whether I actually perform any filtering or just return the unfiltered text.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solution was simple enough in the end :) I just added a static var to the start of the function to prevent infinite loop

```
    static $donethisalready;

if (!$donethisalready){
    $donethisalready = true;

    // do whatever
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your settings, `hook_filter_FILTER_process()` will be invoked (albeit in a round-about way) from within the `drupal_get_form()` and `node_load()` functions.

So at the moment you're simply creating an infinite loop that PHP cannot escape from (`node_load()` calls `hook_filter_FILTER_process()`, which then calls `node_load()` again), hence the out of memory error.

Comment: Thanks Clive, that makes sense - but when you say 'depending on my settings' which settings do you mean? Is there a way I can get around this? Thanks!